# Arduino TinyGPS no data

Tags: arduino, gps, microcontroller

I am using the [TinyGPS](http://arduiniana.org/libraries/tinygps/) library and am trying to display information to get to a specific latitude/longitude via an LCD screen.

I am not getting any data. The output of directionto is "broke" and distanceto and bearingto is 0.

Code redacted

And here is what my pins/hardware look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCv3O.jpg

I am using an [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno), LCD shield and GPS shield by [ITead Studio](http://blog.iteadstudio.com/).

I am hoping it is either the pins or not having a GPS signal.

[Reddit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddit) post: *[Arduino TinyGPS help](http://www.reddit.com/r/arduino/comments/1dlivp/arduino_tinygps_help/)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The baud rate for SoftSerial should be 9600.

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug the system step by step to understand where the problem is.
I would start using only the serial monitor and no display.
Please note that when you switch on a GPS that has been moved for several hundred km, and the same is when you switch it on for the first time, may take a while to get the satellites and start giving out some data. Make sure you are in a open area and wait for 5 to 10 minutes before you declare it as "not working". The next time you will switch it on will be much quicker.
I have checked the documentation of your shield and what they also say is to make sure the Micro SD card you use is support SPI mode but not just the SD mode, also don’t forget to format it into FAT16 , and add a “datalog.txt” file on your card for Arduino to log the information.
Try that and then read the data on the sd card to make sure that is logging.
Come back with the outcome of the above tests and we will try to support you further.